How to Optimize CSV Processing and Aggregation in Python for Large Datasets
I have a Python script that processes and aggregates large CSV files extracted from ZIP archives. Each file is about 350 MB and contains millions of rows.
I'm currently using pandas and concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor to speed up the processing, but it's still taking too long to process all 180 files.
**How can I further optimize this script to reduce the processing time?
**
Here's the code:
import pandas as pd
from zipfile import ZipFile
import os
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import shutil

def process_and_aggregate_log_file(zip_path, final_log_path):
    try:
        print(f"Starting to process file: {zip_path}")
        
        # Extract the zip file
        with ZipFile(zip_path, 'r') as zip_ref:
            zip_ref.extractall(os.path.dirname(zip_path))
        csv_filename = zip_path.replace('.zip', '.csv')
        
        chunk_size = 1000000  # Adjusted chunk size for optimal performance
        processed_chunks = []

        # Read and process the CSV file in chunks
        for chunk in pd.read_csv(csv_filename, chunksize=chunk_size):
            chunk['CIK'] = chunk['uri_path'].str.extract(r'/data/(\d+)/')[0]
            chunk['Filing_ID'] = chunk['uri_path'].str.extract(r'/data/\d+/(\d+)/')[0]
            chunk = chunk.dropna(subset=['Filing_ID'])
            chunk['time'] = chunk['time'].str.strip('"')

            duplicate_mask = chunk.duplicated(subset=['time', 'CIK', 'Filing_ID'], keep=False)
            chunk['robotics_dls'] = duplicate_mask.astype(int)
            chunk = chunk.drop_duplicates(subset=['time', 'CIK', 'Filing_ID'], keep='first')

            chunk['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(chunk['time'], errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            chunk.rename(columns={'time': 'Full Date'}, inplace=True)

            processed_chunks.append(chunk[['Date', 'Full Date', 'CIK', 'Filing_ID', 'robotics_dls']])
            
        # Concatenate all processed chunks
        processed_data = pd.concat(processed_chunks, ignore_index=True)

        # Aggregate the data by Date, CIK, and Filing_ID
        aggregated_data = processed_data.groupby(['Date', 'CIK', 'Filing_ID']).agg(
            Downloads=('Filing_ID', 'size'),
            robotics_dl=('robotics_dls', 'sum')
        ).reset_index()

        # Save the aggregated data to the final log CSV
        aggregated_data.to_csv(final_log_path, index=False)

        print(f"Successfully processed and saved file to: {final_log_path}")
        os.remove(csv_filename)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing file {zip_path}: {e}")

def process_file(file_name, download_dir, final_dir):
    zip_path = os.path.join(download_dir, file_name)
    date_str = file_name.replace('log', '').replace('.zip', '')
    final_log_path = os.path.join(final_dir, f'Final_log{date_str}.csv')
    process_and_aggregate_log_file(zip_path, final_log_path)
    print(f"Completed processing file: {file_name}")

def main():
    # Mount the Google Drive
    drive.mount('/content/drive')

    download_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/TEST/logs'
    final_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/TEST/final_logs2'
    
    os.makedirs(final_dir, exist_ok=True)

    # Get the list of zip files
    files_to_process = [f for f in os.listdir(download_dir) if f.endswith('.zip')]

    # Process files in parallel using ProcessPoolExecutor
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor: 
        futures = [executor.submit(process_file, file_name, download_dir, final_dir) for file_name in files_to_process]
        
        # Wait for all futures to complete
        for future in futures:
            future.result()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()



You should probably consider something like PySpark or PyArrow which have been designed to accommodate large datasets. Pandas is not really meant for this.
